# A regular expression with an optional fixed string

Tags: regex, sed

I have a string with three or four terms separated by colons. The second term may end with a fixed suffix. I need to capture the first two terms excluding the suffix in the first capturing group with one edit.
All the following strings should give a result of `a:b`

```
a:b:c
a:b:c:d
a:b-SUFFIX:c
a:b-SUFFIX:c:d
```

The following expression works for cases with 3 terms but not four.

```
(.*:.*?)(-SUFFIX.*|:.*)
```

Is this doable with one edit?

Comment: Post your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
(.*?:.*?)(-SUFFIX.*|:.*)
```

Comment: Most versions of `sed` lack the capability to do non-greedy regex.  If this solution works for you, what version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: Marvin said that (.*:.*?)(-SUFFIX.*|:.*) works with 3 terms, so I concluded that another '?' would help. Does sed accept one '?' and fail on a second. Maybe sed is not the used tool?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^:]*:[^:]*):.*/\1/; s/-SUFFIX$//' file
a:b
a:b
a:b
a:b
```

#### How it works

- `-r`

  This requests extended regex syntax.
- `s/([^:]*:[^:]*):.*/\1/`

  This keeps only the first two fields.
- `s/-SUFFIX$//`

  If the second field has the suffix, remove it.

#### Mac OSX

On OSX or other BSD systems, try:

```
sed -E -e 's/([^:]*:[^:]*):.*/\1/' -e 's/-SUFFIX$//' file
```

Comment: I believe I mentioned it had to be done with only one edit step.

Comment: No, you asked it if was doable with only one edit, you didn't state that it HAD to be done that way, nor did you explain what you meant by an "edit step".